# How to make a small plume of smoke?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've been trying to make the sphere shoot one plume of smoke (2 frames) and it doesn't shoot it in a small puff but a very large amount that fills up the entire cube in an instant.  How can I change the settings to make this happen?

Here's a screenshot of the sphere physics settings:

[image: sphere physics settings]

Here's a screenshot of the particle settings:

[image: sphere particle settings]

I realize this isn't showing all of the possible settings with the screenshots, so I will attach the .blend

[image]

Comment: I can't download file now, but I'm guessing: decrese size in emission smoke settings, set it to 0.1 or 0.01 for quick test. Also increase smoke domain resolution

Comment: That seemed to produce a better result.  Thanks!